# unable to download ubuntu

Tags: downloads

I tried downloading Ubuntu iso file(64 bit) for many times and every time it is stopping after some seconds showing `network error`.Can anyone please tell me what is the problem(my network is working fine)

Comment: from which os you are trying to download iso file??

Comment: Your question is not clear. It is similiar with "*I want to buy Harley Davidson, but I can't buy it. Why it happens? I have much money.*" Specify from where and how do you download it.

Comment: aggred with @AdeMalsasaAkbar It is not clear what exactly is problem it can be with hardware or the other os from which you are trying to download and also there might be problem with browser specify how and with what tools you are trying to download ubuntu.iso file

Comment: windows 8 @ceator

Comment: Specify from what URL and what download manager did you use for downloading.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop from this website i was unable to download 64 bit version of ubantu 14.04

Comment: i didnt use any download manager..

Comment: form which browser? you are downloading ubuntu??

Comment: google chrome @creator

Comment: if you are using windows use idm or try restarting your system then download

Comment: This is Indonesian mirror for Trusty 64 bit, try to click this link http://kambing.ui.ac.id/iso/ubuntu/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso. Is it can be downloaded? If OK, then go ahead.

Comment: i tried again to download from the mirror u sent...but the same problem again

Answer (score 1):

You could try a mirror that is closer to your geographical location, or use BitTorrent.

See the [alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) page for the links.

Comment: No problem with link I think as it is downloading with my browser form ubuntu Unity desktop